# Flex 4.6 Mobile - Scrolling to the last added item in a dataGrid with variableRowHeight

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, datagrid, air, scroll

I'm trying to set the scroll vertical position of a spark dataGrid to show the items as I add them to the grid. I know you can set the scroll position like this:

> dataGrid.scroller.viewport.verticalScrollPosition = itemPosition*rowHeight;

The problem is that the dataGrid have variableRowHeight, as each row word wraps their name labels, and I don't know how to get each row height. I though of getting the itemRenderer associated with every item as I add it to the grid, and keep the total row height value in a variable, but don't know how to achieve that.

Is there any way to set the scroll position of a dataGrid with variableRowHeight to show the last added item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set your dataprovider, you could do something like

```
dg.validateNow();
dg.verticalScrollPosition=dg.grid.contentHeight+dg.grid.height;
```

Comment: Excellent, this is the way to go... I haven't managed to make it fit perfectly, but this is definitely the way... Thanks!